# How to set the from name in the mail() function

Tags: php, email

When I send a message using the code below, it sends fine. But if I change the $headers to have 'From: Firstname Lastname' it doesn't send for some reason. How do I add my name to the header instead of the email address?

```
  $subject = 'Test message';
  $headers = 'From: mymail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: mymail@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  mail($to, $subject, $themessage, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some (most, I think) email clients check the From field to make sure the domain is the same as the domain that sent the message. This is to prevent spoofing. Try something like 
    `"From: Firstname Lastname <name@domain.com>"`